# Windows 8 Run script on startup

Tags: script, boot, windows-8

Recently installed the Win8 RTM on my MacBook air and made a short AutoHotkey script to reverse the scrolling to be like MacOSX Lion.

My question is... how do you run a script at startup on Windows 8, since the startup folder has been removed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Startup folder still exists.

> In order to quickly navigate to Startup folder, open Windows Explorer
>   and input the following path in address bar with your user profile
>   folder name, and then press Enter.
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<User Profile folder name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
> ```

Source: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/

Comment: Another way to write this path would be:  `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` This should work even if the user's profile folder is on a remote server, or Windows is installed on a different drive.

Answer (score 14):

To open the Startup folder press Start-R, then enter: `shell:startup`

Comment: That's a heck of a shortcut.  Are there any more like it?

Comment: [Shell commands to access the special folders on Windows](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)

Comment: To clarify, if I paste an actual `.bat` file here, it won't run, but if I paste a shortcut to a `.bat` file, it will run?