# How to mirror user's profile files in Windows 7

Tags: windows, backup

I'm looking for a free solution to mirror my entire Windows 7 directory tree to an external drive. I'm currently using Rocobopy and the WinRobocopy GUI frontend, but the problem is that Robocopy can't copy open files, which means that it can't mirror the files that compose the user's profile, for example (\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\usrClass.dat), nor Outlook PST files if Outlook is open, etc. Does anybody know of a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

In the end, the program I found most useful for my purposes was [FreeFileSync](http://freefilesync.sourceforge.net) (though you need to remember to run it as Administrator, so it can access the Shadow Copy service).

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste. Just set up a basic BAT script that runs at startup of the PC for example: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090212102329AAifnWH

Use this to make it run at startup: [Windows 8 Run script on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/463169/windows-8-run-script-on-startup)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't user profile files (usrClass.dat and so on) opened by the OS from the moment it starts up? So they would've been open and locked already by that point.

Comment: do you just want the directory the or a real drive image?

Comment: I want the full directory tree of the entire drive, with all its files. Basically, something like what rsync can produce, but with support for currently open/locked files (I already have Acronis Trueimage, if that's what you mean).